# Does jetty shares threads to handle web socket connections

Tags: java, jetty, java-websocket

I'd like to know whether Jetty server uses the same thread for multiple web sockets?

I need to keep a collection of threads used in websocket's callback handlers, and I am doubt between Set and MultiSet.

I don't want to keep a MultiSet if Set could be used.

Answer (score 2):

Jetty uses multiple threads per connection.

Jetty will only acquire a thread from the ThreadPool for some active read/write operation, that thread will go back into the general ThreadPool when not needed.

Jetty will also acquire Thread for dispatched calls relating to use of Streams in websocket processing (`session.getRemote().getWriter()`, or `onMessage(InputStream)` style of operation)

Tracking threads is not advised.